# React is not displaying img when using require, possible webpack setup issue

Tags: reactjs, image, require

I am attempting to use a map function to build a carousel from an array of objects. One of the objects is the image source. For some reason, using require to specify the img src no longer works. Here is a code snippet that shows the problem.

```
    import myImg from '../images/myImg.jpg';
    ....
    <img src={myImg} alt="This message is not expected to show"></img>
    <img src="../images/myImg.jpg" alt="This message is expected to show"></img>
    <img src={require("../images/myImg.jpg")} alt="Fails when message shows"></img>
```

The result is:

the 1st image displays without an alt message (this is expected)

the 2nd image does not display. The displayed alt message is: "This message is expected to show"

the 3rd image does not display. The displayed alt message is: "Fails when message shows"

I suspect there is something wrong in my wordpack.config settings. I am using file-loader. The code snippet for this is:

```
        loaders: [
  {
    test: /.s?css$/,
    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [
      'file-loader',
    ],
  }
],
```

Is file-loader the wrong choice? Are my settings wrong? I tried this without file-loader and got the same results. This is strange because specifying the file src for an img using require used to work several months ago.

Comment: I think I ruled out webpack. Imoved the project directory to a new folder, then recreated the folder using "npx create-react-app". I then copied the src directory to the new folder and used npm to install all the dependencies without installing webpack or file-loader. Same result. The following snippet does not work: '<img src={require("path-to-my-image/img.jpg")}' alt="not working"></img>. However: import imageImport from 'path-to-my-image/img.jpg'; <img src={imageImport} alt="this word"> </img> Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use require('pathname').default versus require('pathname'). File-loader and webpack are not required.

Require returns a module vs the uri. One of the methods for require is default.

I discovered this by

console.log(require("./images/img.jpg"));

This returns a module versus the uri. Opening the module in console showed the available methods.

I then tried
console.log(require("./images/img.jpg").default);
This returns the same uri to the static image as import.

The obvious advantage of using require vs. import is that require is performed dynamically. The supplied path can come from an array or object. For example

var img = ["img0.jpg", "img1,jpg", "img2.jpg" ];
var i = 1;
<img src={require(`./images/`${i}).default} alt="some message"/>